# How do you set up Eclipse on USB for usage on computers where you do not have admin privileges?

Tags: java, eclipse

As the title said, how would I go about accomplishing that?

Answer (score 1):

Just install eclipce on the usb stick and use it... As far as I know eclipse does not use registry settings...

Comment: The thing, is because of lack of rights and the computer being on a domain, it isn't able to launch nor create a Java project. How would I go about making "create Java project.." possible on a computer from USB?